# How can I get spring.profiles.active value in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

## While running my Spring Boot Application, I am passing --spring.profiles.active=**qa**

```
/user/MyApp --spring.profile.active=qa
```

This **qa** value I will change based on my env.

I need to get this qa value in my **log4j2.xml**

Already tried : ${sys:spring.profiles.active}. It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Spring Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup) for that. Then you can retrieve the comma-separated list of active profiles with:

```
${spring:profiles.active}
```

**Remark**: Since Spring's `Environment` is available only after Spring Boot reconfigures Log4j2, the Spring lookup is not available in the first phases of your application's startup.